# Word VBA Code to select text in a cell, cut and paste special back into the same cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table with two columns and "x" number of rows.

In the 2nd column is formatted text which I would like to change to unformatted text.

The manual way of doing so is:

Select the whole cell in the **2nd column » Cut » Click Edit  »  Click Paste Special  » Click Unformatted**

The idea is to paste the unformatted text back into the cell it was Cut from and then move down to the cell below.

I would really appreciate some code that can apply this to all the cells in the 2nd column of a table.

Comment: can you give sample of formatted and unformatted text?

Comment: Let me fully explain. When I cut and paste special, I remove all formatting but keep line breaks and bullet marks. This is to allow me to import into Excel but maintain the structure of my paragraph

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Is there a way to speak to you more directly so I can explain it better?

Comment: Yes and for some reason I am unable to

Comment: enter the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36328/excel-help)

Comment: I cannot talk on the chat...My rep is not high enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem. A friend had a piece of code which I manipulated to suit my needs:

```
Sub CutAndPasteSpecialUnformatted()

        Dim value As Variable

        ' Process every row in the current table. '
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim rng As Range

        For row = 1 To Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count
            ' Get the range for the rightmost cell. '
            Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            Set rng = Selection.Tables(1).Cell(row, Column:=2).Range

            ' For each, toggle text in rightmost cell. '
            rng.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.Delete
            rng.Select
            Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
            Selection.Delete
            Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            Selection.Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
        Next

End Sub
```